# Handling custom error code in spring cloud load balancer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

In my current project, one of our microservices calls a REST Api of an another microservice and in an error scenario it returns a custom(469) error code.

I'm using a load balanced rest template in the calling service and its throwing an IllegalArgumentException error since 469 error code is not present in HttpStatus enum.

Is there any workaround to resolve this like using raw status codes instead of converting it into an enum?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [469]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:547)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.ResponseData.<init>(ResponseData.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.blocking.client.BlockingLoadBalancerClient.getClientResponse(BlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.blocking.client.BlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(BlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:94)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.lambda$intercept$2(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:129)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.mvc.TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.LazyTraceClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(LazyTraceClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:670)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Spring cloud 2021.0.2 and above
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/1066

To use raw status codes instead of converting into an enum add the following property
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.use-raw-status-code-in-response-data: true

Answer (score 0):

I think we can manipulate the status coming from downstream service using interceptors.

Have you tried [ClientHttpRequestInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html)? Here is an [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor)